# In Opencart, is there a way to restrict access to a page so that only people who are logged in and in a certain group can see the page?

Tags: opencart

Is there a way to restrict access to a page so that only people who are logged in and in a certain group can see the page? I really need help with this. It's for a big client and I don't want to turn it down!

Here's how it would work:

Customer is given a link via email that I will manually send out.
That link is to a page in the store. In order to see it they must log in with their account. And if they are apart of the right group, then Bingo, they can see the page!

I will have 3 groups total and multiple pages. Each page will be branded for the user which is easy. I just need to be able to send out a link to a page and only people in "GROUP A" who are logged in, can see it.

Comment: Which pages exactly are you talking about? Products? Categories? Information? Personal Account?

Comment: It would be random pages I create in the backend for example ABOUT PAGE 1 or ABOUT PAGE 2. It's just random pages, it's not official cart pages.

Comment: You can't create a random page in back-end. You can create product, information or category page, for example. Or you can create an extension, which will have its own pages. Both cases have a bit different approach to the task. So once again: which pages exactly are you talking about - standard OpenCart informational pages or your own extension?

Comment: Standard opencart informational pages! And thanks for clarifying! Also sorry for the delay, I was in the hospital with my wife we just ahd a baby so I didn't get to respond yet!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict access to default pages in OpenCart, you have to create a pretty simple VQMod. It should add a checkup in an common controller file (header.php is the best).

First of all, there's a standard isLogged() function in system/library/customer.php, commonly used like this:

```
$this->customer->isLogged();
```

You can also easily get customer info - id, group ID etc., using standard functions:

```
$this->customer->getId();
$this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Add these checks to index() function in catalog/common/controller/header.php and redirect on fail/success:

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('information/yourpage'));
```

Of course, to implement all this you should know, how to use VQMod.

Comment: Ok cool I just read it. I really have no idea how to use the VQmod, so I  think I'm out of luck. I'll google around some more and see if I can figure something out! Thanks anyways! I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can ask someone to create a VQMod for you. But this is the best and most native solution you can get for your task.

Comment: Ok cool! Thanks so much! I might be able to figure it out! But If not, would you be able to do it if I paid you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost 6 years late, but in case someone else needs this, there's a module here: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=27897